# Save downloaded file in IE 11

Tags: vbscript, internet-explorer-11

I'm trying to identify already opened IE window and save downloaded file [.xml]. I'm using [this online XML editor](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/online_xml_editor.htm) for testing purposes. So once "Do you want to open or save file.xml" popup window appears I need to save file automatically using of .vbs file.

```
Dim objIE
Dim ObjShell
Set ObjShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
For Each wnd In ObjShell.Windows
  If InStr(1, wnd.FullName, "iexplore.exe", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
    Set objIE = wnd
    Exit For
  End If
Next

WScript.Sleep 500
ObjShell.SendKeys "%{s}"
```

Script above returns runtime error:

> Object doesn't support this property or method: 'SendKeys'.

Is there any way how can I save already downloaded file in IE11 using VBScript?

Comment: When in doubt, read the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8c6yea83.aspx). `SendKeys` is a method of [`WshShell`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aew9yb99.aspx) objects, not [`Shell`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774094.aspx) objects.

Comment: I found solution, thanks a lot for your time!